# Different between droplet and a soliton

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, solitons

I am working on the droplet state in a Bose-Bose mixture. I have a question about the difference between the droplet liquid state and the soliton state: How we can treat a droplet state? And how do we know that we have a droplet state?

Answer (score 2):

- Bright/dark solitons are solutions to the GPE. Hence, they are predicted from mean-field theory and stabilised by mechanisms within this approximation.
- Quantum liquid droplets are stabilised by beyond mean-field theory corrections, Lee-Huang-Yang (LHY) terms. The phyisical mechanism in their production, and hence in their dynamics and stability, is different.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum droplest and brigth solitons are two different states in BEC.  Indeed the droplets are three-dimensional solutions that exist even in free space in contrast, solitons require the gas to remain effectively one dimensional.